# Can't change the font size of custom link menu

Tags: css

I've created a custom menu titled SANDUSKY with no-hover as css classes. It is align with HOME,ABOUT,GALLERY,STORE,CONTACT which are the navigation menus. I wanted to customize SANDUSKY, I was able to change the color and font but I cannot increase or make it bigger, the size is just the same with the navigation menus.

Below is the code I used.

```css
.no-hover a:link {
  color: none !important;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.no-hover a:visited {
  color: none !important;
}

.no-hover a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.no-hover a:active {
  color: none !important;
}

.no-hover {
  position: absolute;
  left: -70px;
  font-family: lucida handwriting;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-815" class="no-hover menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-815"><a href="link">SANDUSKY</a></li>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML, thanks

Comment: Include it in the post above not in comments.

Comment: Do you have a website URL we can check? Probably there is CSS rule that overwrites your changes but it is hard to guess.

Comment: I think you are trying to reduce the font-size right?

Comment: Your font-size: 90px; in the .no-hover a:link  is overwriting the 
font-size: 50px!important; in .no-hover. Just remove the, 90px and it should be fine.

Comment: @KalaiselvanA - I'm trying to increase the font-size.

Comment: @ Highdef - I changed the code removing 90px but still the same.

Comment: @MarkDaniel you are trying to increase the font-size hover or what?

Comment: @KalaiselvanA - a:link class

Comment: @MrShemek: it is best to encourage people to put the problem details in the question itself. If people were to start offering links to broken websites, the question would no longer make any sense as soon as the site was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`font-size: 14px;` & `font-size: 16px;` I have changed this two font-size in below code

```css
.no-hover a:link {
  color: blue !important;
  font-size: 150px;
}
.no-hover a:visited{
  color: none !important; 
}
.no-hover a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;  
}
.no-hover a:active{
  color:  none !important;
  font-size: 130px;
}
.no-hover {
  position: absolute; 
  left: -100px;
  font-family: lucida handwriting;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 50px!important;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-815" class="no-hover menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-815"><a href="#">SANDUSKY</a></li>
```

Comment: You do realize that the output can't be seen because of the absolute position of -100px and I think the OP was trying to change the font size in .no-hover class and not the .no-hover a:link class.